# Currency exchange rate tables shows wrong symbols

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I've created a program called "ETM".

Here is the UI:
[image]

This program is used to send data about current currency exchange rates to exchange rate tables. Image of table: 
[image]

These tables are kind of printers and are accessed using print servers through local network. The company, which uses this program has about 50 tables all over country (info about print server: https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/TL-PS110P.html)

The program has two modes: MANUAL MODE and AUTO MODE.

1) MANUAL MODE allows user to enter rates in text boxes, then press "SEND DATA" button and inputted currency rates will be shown on all tables.

2) AUTO MODE gets currency rates from service in every 20 seconds and does the same logic as MANUAL MODE, if rates have changed.

```
// Table object implementation
public class ExchangeTable : ITable {
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public IPAddress IPAddress { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
    public string LogMessage { get; set; }
}    

// Currency object implemetation
public class Currency {
    public object CurrencyName { get; set; }
    public string BuyPrice { get; set; }
    public string SellPrice { get; set; }
}
```

When the program starts, user checks the tables from List Check Box, then uses MANUAL MODE-s "SEND DATA" button, or AUTO MODE-s "START PROCESS" button
to execute operation.

```
// data sending logic
public virtual void SendDataToTable(ITable table) {
        if (table != null && table.Currencies != null) {
            using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient()) {
                try {
                    string dataToSend = GetPrintString(GetPrices(table));
                    client.Connect(table.IPAddress, table.Port);
                    if (client.Connected) {
                        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataToSend);
                        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream()) {
                            stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        }

                        if (table is ExchangeTable)
                            ((ExchangeTable)table).LogMessage = "SUCCESS";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    if (table is ExchangeTable)
                        ((ExchangeTable)table).LogMessage = "FAILURE: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

After this everything works fine. all 50 tables show correct data, but after some period of time (about 1 hour or more) 5 tables (always the same tables) show wrong symbols, rest 45 tables still show correct data. All these 50 tables are same. I have no idea why it happens only to 5 tables and not to all of them. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in another part of your code, most likely, since in your published code the table is just an already predefined argument, already containing the CurrencyName object. Try to post the code in which you define the CurrencyName for each table.

However, I wonder why CurrencyName is an object and not something more specific, like string or enum. In such a case, the wrong symbol error would probably cause a runtime error which you could find easier.

Comment: Other part of code doesn't have any problem. If it does, other tables would fail too. I have already tested and found out that the program sends byte buffer correctly. At first all tables show correct values, but after some period of time, 5 of them shows junk symbols (even if no new bytes were sent from the program)